# DRM protection for Video

Tags: html, html5-video

is there any way to achieve DRM/third party protection for video tag in html5 through Javascript?

sri

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use DRM on HTML5 video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983555/is-there-a-way-to-use-drm-on-html5-video)

Comment: check this article which i wrote recently : http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/  it explains in details about how to achieve multi-drm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, at least not without writing your own decryption algorithm and decryption key within the script.  But if you do that, end users will obtain all they need to decrypt the content anyway.  DRM is futile at best, and actively harmful to end users at worst.  Don't even attempt to use it.